# SQL copying old records to new records on the same table

Tags: sql

I have a stocktake with a list of items and their stock counts. I want to add a copy of each item to the same stocktake with the same order code but a different item number from a different table. The original stocktake items have an item number > 1000000. The new stocktake items have an item number < 1000000. I also want the new items to take the stock counts showing for the original items on the stocktake. Using Interbase databases on firebird servers. Does anyone have a query for this?

**Stocktake table** (where the old items are currently sitting)

Stocktakedtl_lintstocktakenum (stocktake number)

stocktakedtl_lintitemnumber (unique item number)

stocktakedtl_strordercode (model code of the item)

stocktakedtl_dblstockcount (count of item on the stocktake)

**Range table** (where the new and old items exist. the match the old items order code, but have a unique item number)

range_lintitemnumber (unique item number)

range_strordercode (model code of the item)

Comment: Write a `SELECT` query that produces the rows that you want. Then use `INSERT INTO stocktake SELECT ...`

Comment: Add the database you are working on